# Integer with ASCII values to string

Tags: python, string, ascii

I have an integer containing four ASCII codes for four chars:

```
0x31323334
```

I need to convert this integer to a string:

```
"1234" ~ "\x31\x32\x33\x34"
```

Is there better solution than this?

```
mystring = '%0*x' % (8, 0x31323334) # "31323334"
mystring.decode('hex') # "1234"
```

Comment: I think your way is OK. I would use instead `str('0x31323334')[2:].decode('hex')` as I think it's more readable, but the basic idea is the same.

Comment: @Eduardo Perhaps you mean `hex(0x31323334)[2:].decode('hex')`?

Comment: @Dunes: that's better! I did mean the sloppier version : )

Comment: @Dunes: Almost - works for this case, but not in general. If the number starts with zeros then it either loses characters of fails with a TypeError.

Comment: @Scott Issue with zeroes is very important for me, I have to consider that.

Comment: @all what about binascii.unhexlify(mystring) ? is it identical to mystring.decode('hex')?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it's better, but :)

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('>L', 0x31323334)
'1234'
```

Comment: In Python 2.6 / 2.7 I get '\x00\x00\x00\x001234'. Works for Python 2.5 though.

Comment: 64 bit, I suppose... never used that package. can you try as I edited, with struct.pack('>L', 0x31323334)? it should be big-endian, 4 bytes wide.

Comment: Yes it's a 32 vs. 64 bit thing, nothing to do with the Python version - my misunderstanding. It makes no difference with the 'L' format, on 64 bit `struct.calcsize('L')` is 8.

Comment: Using `'>I'` will be more portable.  Most 64-bit systems have 64-bit longs, the *only* exception is Windows.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I don't think there's a difference between `'>L'` and `'>I'` - according to the docs (and my tests) they are both the 'standard' 4 bytes long. It's only different if you use the native size, which might be 8 for a `'L'` on non-Windows 64-bit Python.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll get simpler than a format string and then a decode (needs Python 2.6+):

```
>>> "{0:08x}".format(0x31323334).decode('hex')
'1234'
```